# Can't click on link inside an outlook email sent by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a problem when i send email using Rails email text format, the email contains a link for password reset and all work fine, but when i open email in `outlook` the link is shown but can't click on. this problem is only when send an email to an hotmail/live/outlook account, is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link. It may be a simple matter of changing your Outlook settings.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/enable-or-disable-links-and-functionality-in-phishing-e-mail-HA001229962.aspx